# How to load jQuery in JS Bin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to run jQuery code in jsbin.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jsbin.com - You can select the javascript framework from **Include Dropdown on right side**.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is also a good option.

Answer (score 1):

you should know that jsbin is divided into two coding window...

*left side* (**JavaScript**)

put js codes here like jQuery..

*right side* (**HTML**)

if you notice, you can write html/css codes here...
on the top here, you can find a select option, choose jQuery so that your jquery codes will run...

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you have default example just click preview

hence the message

> Hello World - this was inserted using
>   JavaScript

Comment: Yes, but i want to run jquery statements here, just like `$('#hello').html('Hello World - this was inserted using jQuery code');`

Comment: try using http://jsfiddle.net/ instead choose the proper framework from the left side

Answer (score 0):

Try Googles [JQuery playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#jquery) website instead.

Comment: thats pretty cool, but with Google playground I can't share the code with others